# Is it possible to access Sqlite database deployed on an android device webserver, from web api on windows PC using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api, android-sqlite

I have an android device which will have Sqlite database. I want to access this database from a Web API (residing on windows PC) service using linq.
Both the android device and the windows PC will be connected through LAN.

Could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

No you will not be able to access the sqlite database on the android phone from the web api,  You should use a server side database.  I would make sure any changes made to the android device database are sent to the server side database.